# Magento 2.1.0 blank checkout page

Tags: php, magento, checkout, magento2

I have been trying to create a new custom payment method in Magento 2.1.0 version. I have got an issue. Check out page was working earlier but after creating layouts/webs (the front side flow) my check out page went blank. I removed my plugin and setup:upgrade, cache:flush. But I still have the same issue.

[image]

Comment: I have tried this too . It did not work  though

Replace in customer module in the file authentication-popup.js:
autocomplete: window.checkout.autocomplete
with: autocomplete: ((window.checkout && window.checkout.autocomplete) ? window.checkout.autocomplete : null),
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125034/js-errors-magento-2

Comment: Have you check log file and error file ?

Comment: Yes. It says "[2016-08-18 06:39:55] main.CRITICAL: Class Merchantfirst\Primspay\Model\Prismpay does not exist [] []
"

Comment: This is my model class code/Merchantfirst/Prismpay/Model/Prismpay.php

<?php
namespace Merchantfirst\Prismpay\Model;

/**
 * Pay In Store payment method model
 */
class Prismpay extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod
{

protected $_code = 'prismpay';
protected $_isOffline = true;
}
?>

Comment: I don't find any issue with my model.

Comment: please for temporary disable **Merchantfirst** extension

Comment: I am having the same issue but only if i installed 2 different custom payment modules, i created my self. but installing it and disabling one of them works but enabling both brings this wierd error. please anyone able to solve this issue.